# Is it possible to make a flex div to sit where there is a space they can go?

Tags: css, flexbox

Sorry for my question that is not so clear, but what I really want to do is like this. I want to align divs like on the first picture, not like in the second picture. The parent div will have flex style. If there is any solution for this, would be great to know it. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Do you have to use flexbox? This feels more like a grid layout to me.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I have to use flexbox for some reason, but using grid would it be possible?

Comment: It's definitely possible with grid, I'm afraid I don't know if it's possible with flexbox.

Comment: I want the 3rd div to go on a new line like on the picture below when the 3rd div has width of more than 50%, is it possible too?

Answer (score 1):

**Here is with flexbox:**

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.main-container > * {
  flex: 1;
}

.left-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.left-container > * {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="left-container">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
  </div>
  <div>c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want the 3rd div to go on a new line like on the picture below when the 3rd div has width of more than 50% automatically, is it possible too?

Comment: The a,b,c div should be child of main container. We shouldn't have left-aligned div for a, and b. Thanks

Comment: in that case, i don't know how to do with flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert another grid container inside your flex. (Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645879/css-grid-inside-flexbox-not-working-as-expected-only-on-chrome) for grid inside a flex container.)

And Use `grid-template-area` property to define the overall grid structure.

HTML

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="D1"></div>
  <div class="D2"></div>
  <div class="D3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "D1 D3"
    "D2 D3";
}

.D1 { grid-area: D1; }

.D2 { grid-area: D2; }

.D3 { grid-area: D3; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way for the 3rd div to go on a new line like on the 2nd picture, when it has width of more than 50 % ?

Comment: Grid will remain in this form only however responsive. I couldn't understand you better because 2nd div will have fixed width relative to other divs so grid structure will be maintained. More information or code would be needed for different approach to your problem.

Comment: Well, all the divs (like 1, 2 and 3 etc) have their own width (like 30%, 50% or 60% etc). They sit next to the previous element if there is a space in row. E.g. if the first element has 30% width, and second has 50% of width, then they will lay on the same row, but second div has 80% of width, then it will lay on a new line. And the thing is, all the div has different heights, so an element that comes on a new line can sit without gap if an there is a space for it. So the third div will sit on a new line if its width is 60%, and just beneath div 1 when it is 30%. Hope that makes sense. Thanks